# Rails app on Heroku - View not rending in Mozilla Firefox browser only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, heroku

I have a simple Rails app deployed on Heroku with a custom domain (whosaheadnow.com). It has two views: `welcome/index.html.erb` and `search/show.html.erb` [(check out the source code here)](https://github.com/ktravers/whos-ahead-now/tree/master/app/views). The `search#show` view is supposed to render JSON information parsed from the Huffpost Pollster API, which it does successfully in Chrome, Safari, and Internet Explorer browsers.

Problem is, when you navigate from the `welcome#index` page to the `search#show` page in Firefox, the show page doesn't render anything between the `<body></body>` tags. Instead, it displays the footer text and links only at the top of the browser window [(go to the homepage in Firefox](http://www.whosaheadnow.com) then click on one of the images to see what I'm talking about). The `welcome#index` page works fine in Firefox; it's just the `search#show` page that's not rendering as intended. This behavior holds true for production (when deployed on Heroku) and when I run the app locally.

I scoured Mozilla, Rails, and Heroku's docs, but can't figure out what's causing the problem. Thank you in advance to anyone who can point me towards the solution, and please let me know if there's any additional information that'd be helpful for me to post.

*Version info:*
- Rails 4.2.0
- Ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]
- heroku-toolbelt/3.30.3 (x86_64-darwin14)
- json 1.8.2
- Mozilla Firefox 36.0.1 on Mac OSX

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox 36.0.1 on Mac.

Comment: Same here. Firefox 36.0.4 on OS X.

Comment: Interesting - it works if you go directly to the [link I originally provided](http://www.whosaheadnow.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&commit.x=247&commit.y=143). But if you go to the [homepage](http://www.whosaheadnow.com), then click on one of the images, it doesn't render the table. Thanks for pointing that out - I updated my question to reflect that.